# Accessing Petrel 3D window framebuffer

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I'm looking for a way to access the framebuffer of a `Window3D` other than `Window3D.SaveBmp`. The preferred solution would be to be able to draw the scene graph to an offscreen buffer, but other ways of accessing the framebuffer could also work.

Comment: Why do you want to access the frame buffer?

Comment: I ask because I'm currently porting Petrel's 3D rendering to use MeshViz.

Comment: @Skizz: just as a part of some testing we're doing. I'm kind of baffled that there is a way to save to file, but no way of storing the same data to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not supported by Ocean for Petrel.

I agree it might seem a bit strange that saving a bitmap is supported but not accessing an in-memory copy. The reason is simply historical as the underlying C++ framework of Petrel encapsulates most of the oiv viewer and scenegraph. This encapsulation *did* provide a nice way to store the bitmap but not a way to get an in-memory copy, so we simply went for the easy win first. That said, adding this API would not be rocket science, just work.

Ocean dude.